# Метрики качества

Tags: машинное-обучение, метрики

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Считаю по формуле FPR = FP/(FP+TN) = 30+1/(30+1+50+70+60) = 0.15
Откуда число равно 15. Неправильный ответ.
Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Истинные значения находятся в столбцах, в строках - предсказанные значения.
Соответственно для для первого класса:

```
TP (True Positive): 20
FP (False Positive): 30 + 1 = 31
```